# JS exported constants as TypeScript type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I work on a project with JS/TS mixed support
I'm looking for a way to reduce code duplication with JS string constants when wrapping them as Typescript types.

For example, I have constants for log type:

```js
// logTypes.js    
export const ERROR = 'error'
export const INFO = 'info'
```

Reexport them:

```js
// constants.js    
export * as LOG_TYPES from './logTypes.js'
```

And now I want to provide a TS type for this constants:

```js
// types.d.ts
import { LOG_TYPES } from './constants'

export type LogType = ???
```

Obviously, I can declare the type like this and this will work:

```js
// type LogType = "error" | "info", excellent
export type LogType = typeof LOG_TYPES.INFO | typeof LOG_TYPES.ERROR
```

But I think this is redundant, and also creates two points to be maintainable when somebody needs to extend the set of constants.

So, actually I would like to write something like this:

```js
// Does not work as desired
// type LogType = any, meh
export type LogType = typeof LOG_TYPES[string]
```

I know there is a difference between types and values, but this specific part of import/export should be statically analyzable so I think there should be a way to do this I don't know about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the idea indeed, but `typeof LOG_TYPES` cannot be indexed by `string`, but `keyof typeof LOG_TYPES`:

```
type LogType = typeof LOG_TYPES[keyof typeof LOG_TYPES]
//   ^? "error" | "info"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAZA8gcQPoBUCaACgKIDKSA3gFBI1IQAeMA9gE4AuS8TwUHRASvzT8kAXiQByCCxasJ1Wg2btO3XkgCSAOQBiaMZICWwAGZN5AX0qU2ATxjIUTAOY57ycXYdMTqTLkJSAG0AawhbHyQvCEj0bHxiEgBdSgB6VNoAPQB+SiA)